# How do I properly use 'yield return' with TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()?

Tags: xml, wpf, multithreading, wcf, c#-4.0

I have a long running process in a WCF service that may return a large XML. To avoid running out of memory, I decided it would be a good idea to query the xml in chunks. so I did this:

```
Task<IEnumerable<XElement>> aTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.QueryServer());
```

And the implementation of QueryServer()

```
private IEnumerable<XElement> QueryServer()
{
    using (var s = new MyService())
    {
        for (DateTime halfADay = StartDate; halfADay < EndDate.Date.AddHours(12); halfADay = halfADay.AddHours(12))
        {
            yield return s.MyServiceClient.DownloadLargeXElement(
                halfADay,
                halfADay.AddHours(12));
        }
    }
}
```

My problem, is that the UI will hang if I use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`
but If I don't use it then my UI won't be updated once it's done querying the XML

```
aTask.ContinueWith(
    (a) =>
    {
        if(a.IsCompleted)
        {
            foreach(XElement row in a.Result.Select(x => x.Elements()).First())
            {
                DataRow dataRow = this.XElementToDataRow(row);
                MyTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
    },
    **TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()**);
```

I know this is happening because when it reaches my foreach it then queries the server but at this moment we're back on the UI thread. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to use `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`, which supports progress reporting, and you can pass an arbitrary object as a parameter of the report.

Comment: I'm not sure about the whole question, but for the note, `yield` is just a shortcut allowing not to manually create and return a list in a method. It does nothing to help asynchronous calls or stuff like that.

Comment: The reason why I thought of using yield is to avoid filling up the XElement and risk running out of memory. Instead, I'd like to send chunks of the XML to my DataTable which is then displayed in my UI.